# Select Case inside another Select

Tags: mysql, sql, select, case

I’m trying to apply a CASE to a column that I create.
But the problem is that I have a select inside another select
And I’m using the value of that subquery to make the select case
How should I do this?

```
SELECT
gc.IDGastosComunes,
v.IDPropiedad,
v.Depto,
v.NombreDueno,
(SELECT u2.IDCategoria
    FROM usuarios_tipos u2
    WHERE u2.IDUsuario = v.IDDueno AND
                u2.IDTipo = 10) AS gc.IDCategoria, <-- This return an int -> 1, 2 or 3
    CASE
        WHEN IDCategoria = 1 THEN 'Convenio'
        WHEN IDCategoria = 2 THEN 'Plus'
        WHEN IDCategoria = 3 THEN 'Preferente'
        WHEN IDCategoria = 4 THEN 'Premium'
        WHEN IDCategoria = 5 THEN 'La Serena'
        ELSE ''
  END AS Categoria, <-- This has to show the string
gc.monto,
gc.FechaEmisionPago AS Periodo
FROM
gastos_comunes gc
JOIN vcartera_propiedades v ON (v.IDPropiedad=gc.IDPropiedad)
WHERE v.IDGrupo = 1
```

Comment: Since you're only expecting one match per outer query record anyway, why not just join? It's often cheaper than correlated subqueries.

Comment: I tried but the condition was cutting the expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would typically move the `case` expression inside the subquery:

```
SELECT
    gc.IDGastosComunes,
    v.IDPropiedad,
    v.Depto,
    v.NombreDueno,
    (
        SELECT CASE u2.IDCategoria
            WHEN 1 THEN 'Convenio'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'Plus'
            WHEN 3 THEN 'Preferente'
            WHEN 4 THEN 'Premium'
            WHEN 5 THEN 'La Serena'
            ELSE ''
        END
        FROM usuarios_tipos u2
        WHERE u2.IDUsuario = v.IDDueno AND u2.IDTipo = 10
    ) AS Categoria
    gc.monto,
    gc.FechaEmisionPago AS Periodo
FROM gastos_comunes gc
JOIN vcartera_propiedades v ON v.IDPropiedad=gc.IDPropiedad
WHERE v.IDGrupo = 1
```

Side note: this would need to be tested, but likely, your query can be rewritten to use a `(LEFT) JOIN` instead of an inline subquery, which would make the syntax much shorter. That would look like:

```
SELECT
    gc.IDGastosComunes,
    v.IDPropiedad,
    v.Depto,
    v.NombreDueno,
    CASE u2.IDCategoria
            WHEN 1 THEN 'Convenio'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'Plus'
            WHEN 3 THEN 'Preferente'
            WHEN 4 THEN 'Premium'
            WHEN 5 THEN 'La Serena'
            ELSE ''
    END AS Categoria
    gc.monto,
    gc.FechaEmisionPago AS Periodo
FROM gastos_comunes gc
JOIN vcartera_propiedades v ON v.IDPropiedad=gc.IDPropiedad
LEFT JOIN  usuarios_tipos u2 ON u2.IDUsuario = v.IDDueno AND u2.IDTipo = 10
WHERE v.IDGrupo = 1
```

Comment: Ohhhh.. SELECT CASE IDCATEGORIA... im an idiot
I tried this a lot, but in a wrong form